# The property is not a declared property on type 'class'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I got the error `The property 'Rank' is not a declared property on type 'MasterUser'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.` I checked my model class and it is there.

```
public class MasterUser
{
    //many other properties...
    public virtual char Rank { get; set; }
    //more properties below
}
```

I also checked my db context and it is also there and mapped perfectly.

```
public class BBDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MasterUser> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        #region MUSR_USRID mapping

        //Mapped properties above....
        modelBuilder.Entity<MasterUser>()
            .Property(usr => usr.Rank).HasColumnName("MUSR_RANK");
        //More mapped properties..

        modelBuilder.Entity<MasterUser>().ToTable("dbo.MUSR_FIL");
        #endregion

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

In the table, `MUSR_RANK` is nullable with a char datatype.

How can I fix this? Does the database have an effect on this? I am currently using SQL Server 2000.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Primitive Data Types Supported in the Entity Data Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382832.aspx)

So you have to use a `string` instead of a `char`, I think

and add some datas in `OnModelCreating`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MasterUser>()
            .Property(usr => usr.Rank).HasColumnName("MUSR_RANK")
            .HasMaxLength(1)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);
```

Comment: Would this affect the data to be passed from EF to the database? Like, would it automatically convert `string` from EF to `char` in the database?

Comment: @Musikero31 yes, with the control of the Max and Fixed length, you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: So you're saying that even if the data type of `MUSR_RANK` is `char` in the database, EF will easily convert the mapping type string to char right?

Comment: @Musikero31 that's what I say, but it shouldn't be to hard to test, no ? Or did you face a problem ?

Comment: I think this will do for the mean time. But will still have to check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and was searching for help when I found this page. I know this post is old, but since my solution is different, I am posting in case it helps someone else. I am using EF 6.

My error was caused because I inadvertently made a property of my model class readonly.

```
[Key]
[StringLength(10)]
public string ProjectNumber { get; }
```

The EF error wasn't very descriptive of the problem. As soon as I added the set accessor, the error disappeared.